# Chocolate Fluid animation In After Effects

Tags: animation, effects, adobe-after-effects

Basically i'm designing one candy themed game and i chose cheese plus chocolate theme as you can see in below image

[image]

and upon dragging chocolate [fluid properties] it should flow downside like chocolate as below

[image]

but the issue is i can't find idea either on net or tutorial to achieve such effect; what i tried is making rectangle in after effect and then change in path frame to final path but it looks so unrealistic.any one have idea??
**after effect not necessary for animation but just keep in mind that final output should work with unity :)**

Comment: So you have the curvy chocolate but you're just having trouble animating it in from the top?

Comment: I don't know how you made the chocolate, but maybe it's made from a rectangle combining multiple effects to create the inner glow and the wave, you could gradually shift the effect values over time and perhaps scale and position animation to bring it down.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Yeah so basically assume we have a glass on hand and what happen if you pour chocolate from above? it starts flowing like liquid to downside right? that's what i want :)

Comment: @Joonas and making chocolate was pretty easy. drew shape via pen tool and made fill colour to brown shade and gave inner shadow with more dark brown :)

Comment: Were you able to do it all based on my description? You can answer your of question if you like.

Comment: @Joonas i tried position alongside with change in path (after effect) with/without motion blur and ease in but not anything helping to make it realistic. i don't need tutorial on how to make animation but if you only can find gif or video which have same animation it will be enough for me and i'll take it as answer :) just need a reference so i can get inspired

Comment: @Joonas can u reply your comment as answer? so i can accept it :)

Comment: No, I think your own answer is better than what I was suggesting in terms of the end result. I also don't feel like writing a detailed answer myself... It's a shame though since I believe you can't reclaim your own bounty. Your answer could benefit from some deeper description on how you got to the end result. — One thing though... It might be even better if you added [some highlights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtouA.png).

Comment: @Joonas It's perfect; the thing i was missing is highlights! will add it in my animation and for sure i'll share my answer too and if peoples will like it i'm sure i can have my bounty in form of UPVOTES!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Made It Possible Via After Effects**

all i did was using path change keyframe and changed path along time;
used graph editor to make it slow and fast; it's not perfect but now i may have my animation ready by practice.thanks for your all comments :)

**[Here Goes My Animation](https://streamable.com/r2jxo)**